# How can be set system compiler variable sys.version externally

Tags: install4j

I tried setting the sys.version variable from the build script where I am also setting the other user created compiler variable while running the ./install4jc command for building the installer. It is not setting  the variable and it's saying giving a warning message: [WARNING] The variable 'sys.version' is a system variable that cannot be overridden.

The requirement is the version number should not be hard coded in the Installer file. Please advise how can I achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

On the command line, specify the version with

```
-r [version]
```

Ant task as well as gradle and maven plugins have corresponding parameters.